# How to build and run dApps written in Solidity without ethers?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, ide

Is there a way to **test** build and run dApps with Solidity back-end that does not require downloading blockchains or ethers?

I have created an account in Ethereum Wallet, but have been unable to download the entire blockchain.

Are there any IDEs or some platform of the sort to build Solidity contracts, write the front end dApp and *simulate* a real world application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is [truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) ethereum framework that allows you to write Solidity smart contracts and also build your front end in HTML/CSS/JS (`truffle init webpack`) or use your [custom build setup](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/build_processes)

Every truffle project has `truffle.js` file where you specify your ethereum node that you want to talk to. So, for your case, it's best to use [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) which is your local private ethereum blockchain that only you have control over with some prepopulated accounts with ether in it. No need to wait for synchronization of some other blockchain.

There is also [Ethereum Studio IDE](https://live.ether.camp/) which is [cloud9](https://c9.io/) based online IDE.

The easiest way is to run [Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) or [Parity](https://parity.io) clients that can also be ran with your custom development chain, so you can easily mine your own ether, create accounts, deploy contracts.

Comment: You lost me at testrpc. Would I require it alongside Truffle? I have installed Mist. Is it an alternative to Truffle?

Comment: No. Truffle is a framework for writing smart contracts. It's NOT an alternative to Mist. If you want to build contracts with truffle, you would need some ethereum node to run alongside like testrpc or geth(which Mist runs inside)

Comment: I found testrpc w/ Truffle tutorials. Is there a geth and Truffle tutorial? Can I run it while simultaneously downloading the blockchain (using `geth --testnet`)?

Comment: yes, you can. You can use the same tutorial, just change your `truffle.js` file when you want to point to your geth node. You would also have to change port, since both will try to run on the same one: `8545` `testrpc -p 8546`